# Problems getting DataTriggers to make properties change

Tags: wpf, properties, datatrigger

I have looked thru endless answers  to this problem, so far without any success. I have a trivial UserControl of my own, that simply defines a pair of new Dependency properties named SetText and SetBackground.  Both work as expected, but only SetText is actually used in this example.

```
<Grid Height="25" Width="200">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTest">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

I have placed this usercontrol on a page.

This user control is placed on another page. The code for that is as follows :

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="25">
                <views:DependencyUserControl1 
                    x:Name="tester"
                    Width="200"
                    Height="25"
                    SetText="Hello world"                   
                    BorderBrush="Magenta"
                    BorderThickness="2">
                    
                    <views:DependencyUserControl1.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="views:DependencyUserControl1">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <!--So, we are listening for the Btn1(Below) Mouseover, & then these (TextBlock) Setters 
                                are implemented but the Button's Color changes relies on the Buttons 
                                code listener, so in this case Btn2 -->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SliderValue, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="views:DependencyUserControl1.Background" Value="Blue" />
                                    <Setter Property="views:DependencyUserControl1.Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    <Setter Property="views:DependencyUserControl1.FontWeight" Value="Heavy" />
                                    <Setter Property="views:DependencyUserControl1.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtBlock2, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </DataTrigger>-->
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </views:DependencyUserControl1.Style>


                            <!--Style="{StaticResource txtblk1}"-->                 
                </views:DependencyUserControl1>
            </Grid>
```

All I want to be able to do is to have the 4 properties shown in the DataTrigger section change when the specified control is "MousedOver".  The Triggers are hit as expected, and the Setters all work as defined, BUT but my problem comes if I have defined any of these properties previously in the control, .  EG I add a Background = Magenta" in the Controls main Properties setup section, then that property does NOT change when the trigger are is fired. The same applies to any other properties I want to change via a trigger, they cannot be declared previously.

I feel sure there must be a simple a way to allow the coder to specify the basic properties of any controls, but still have the triggers like this overwrite them ?

Comment: The problem is value precedence. A local value (set directly on an element) always has higher precedence than the value of a Style Setter. Add Style Setters for the default property values instead of local values.

Comment: Thanks for that, I went thru  the pages on  "Dependency Property Value Precedence " which helped quite a bit, it is just a shame there are no code examples in there to clarify some of the concepts it espouses !!